# Unable to execute command line in checkstyle

Tags: java, checkstyle

I want to configure a check in checkstyle plugin. I have made a config.xml file and a Test file in java. When on terminal I execute the command `java -jar E:/Downloads/checkstyle-8.38-all.jar -c /config.xml Test.java` it shows `Files to process must be specified, found 0.` whereas I have mentioned the files and they are in the same project. I have made my default download folder in E drive.I have also added jar file to external Libraries.[image]

The path of jar file is correct, I have checked it multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're in the wrong directory. `Checkstyle` can't find your `Test.java` file.

So before running `java -jar E:/Downloads/checkstyle-8.38-all.jar -c /config.xml Test.java`, enter into the 'src' directory with command: `cd src`.

Comment: You must verify the working directory the command is being executed in from your IDE. Like mentioned in answer, you are probably defaulted to the base project directory. I would change `Test.java` to `src\Test.java` or the path to where the file is.